# Pure numpy implementation of Watts-Strogatz Algorithm

Tags: python, numpy, networkx, graph-theory

I want to write a pure numpy implementation of the Watts-Strogatz random graph generation algorithm.

Below is a function which uses numpy functions to select and remove appropriate edges, and find all initial candidate edges to replace the removed edges with. However, I did not find a way to  select a candidate edge, add it to the network, remove a the selected edge from the candidate pool and add the removed edge back into the candidate pool. Any ideas how this could be done in pure numpy?

```py
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

def WS_gen(A, N, k, p):
    """
    N : Number of nodes 
    k : coordination number of 1-d ring graph
    p : rewiring probability
    A : adjacency matrix of a valid ring graph with appropriate N, k
    """

    # considering only upper triangle to consider each edge only once 
    A_u = np.triu(A)

    # find matrix with edges to remove and remove them
    x = np.random.rand(*A.shape)
    x = np.where(x > (1-p), 1, 0)
    edges_to_be_removed = np.array(x*A_u, dtype=int)
    A_u = A_u - edges_to_be_removed
    
    # find matrix with initial candidate edges to add
    # A_inv is the candidate pool, not the inverse of A
    A_inv = np.where(A > 0, 0, 1)
    A_inv = A_inv - np.diag(np.diag(A_inv))
    
    # This is where I have to resort to using a for loop
    # did not find a valid numpy implementation
    # iterate overall removed edges and add corresponding new edge
    for i,j in zip(*np.nonzero(edges_to_be_removed)):
        # pick new edge from candiate pool
        j_new = np.random.choice(np.nonzero(A_inv[i])[0])
        
        # add edge to network
        A_u[i,j_new] = 1
       
        # remove added edge from candidate pool
        A_inv[[i,j_new], [j_new, i]] = 0
       
        # add removed edge to candidate pool
        A_inv[[i,j], [j, i]] = 1
    
    # reinstate lower triangle of adjacency matrix
    return (A_u + A_u.T)
```

An initial idea I had was to use `np.tile(A_inv, N)` to have a candidate pool for each node and  then use them individually, but I could not figure out how to implement the idea.